# excel: still struggling with sum product ignoring blanks

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet with a lot of data there are result columns adjacent to all of the data.  I can put a range on each column of data using a max and min cell and by using sumproduct i can only see the results that fall withing the specified max and min for each column of data.  I am running into a problem now because I added an iferror in the data cells to give a blank when there is an error.  ie  `=iferror(b3/c4,"")`
I tried to account for this by adjusting my sumproduct formula like this:

```
=IF(AND(($KM9:$BFW9<>""),SUMPRODUCT(($KM9:$BFW9<=$KM$1:$BFW$1)*($KM9:$BFW9>=$KM$2:$BFW$2))=COLUMNS($KM9:$BFW9)),BKR9,"")
```

but I just can't seem to get it to work or know what to do next

Comment: It won't work. Because you are trying to do math on a text, albeit an empty text but a text none the same.

Comment: Ah ok,  I guess I can get around this by making the iferror =-10000, so it will be outside of any range and therefore ignored.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction